# Setup notify-send click action

Tags: focus, notify-send

Given some simple `notify-send` command inside a bash script such as

```
notify-send "test"
```

How can I make a determinate window gain focus when the user clicks that notification? I thought playing around with the `-a` switch would do something, but I can't get it to work either on GNOME Shell and XFCE .

Answer (score 3):

It seems `notify-send` can't do this. This Arch Linux thread provides more details as answer:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172965

taken from the link above:

> No, notify-send doesn't support the use of actions/buttons.

> Maybe this link will be useful for you : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDesignGuidelines

it seems that the design guidelines don't recommend action buttons in notifications, rather recommend a popup window from the application if additional action is required/needed.

last but not least `dunstify` seems to support action buttons.

Comment: please expand the solution from the link you gave into your answer here and add link to thread you found solution from there to referred

Comment: thanks, added some details.

Comment: +1 for using [Dunst](https://dunst-project.org/) for its customizability and support for actions. Notifications can still be triggered with `notify-send`, so a solution explicitly showing how to do this (maybe I'll have time to write it later) pretty much settles this.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626458/68678) is now wrong as notify-send gained the necessary bits in [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libnotify/-/merge_requests/18) merge request.

```bash
# Show a button with text action1, notification with summary text "test"
# Sender gets a "Focus Window" event back on click
% notify-send --action 'action1=Focus Window' test
action1
```

One still needs to have the place that called notify-send to handle the response and act adequately, whereas [Dunst](https://dunst-project.org/) seems to have a more direct support for this use case.

Some notification implementations treat the `default` action special, [as per the spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html), usually making the entire notification clickable without the clutter of adding extra buttons.

```bash
# Show a clickable notification(usually) with summary text "This is a notification!"
# Sender gets a "Open URL" event back on click
% notify-send --action 'default=Open URL' 'This is a notification!'
```